# jnidispatch.dll not found in resource path after compile to native with gluonfx

Tags: java, java-native-interface, graalvm, gluonfx

I'm compiling to native a javafx app using gluonfx plugin.
To perform some network functions I needed to add some **pcap** dependencies, I tested in debug mode and everything goes fine. But after compile to native I have the following error when I try to use the implemented function:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: pcap.spi.Service: Provider pcap.jdk7.internal.DefaultService could not be instantiated
     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
     at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804)
     at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722)
     at java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
     at pcap.spi.Service$Creator.<clinit>(Service.java:343)
     at [project path].VdsConfiguratorService.getNetworkInterfaces(VdsConfiguratorService.java:27)
     at [project path].vdsswitchconfig.VdsSwitchConfigurator.<init>(VdsSwitchConfigurator.java:20)
     at [project path].GuiExtraStarter.show(GuiExtraStarter.java:84)
     at [project path].FxMainMenu.lambda$updateContent$7(FxMainMenu.java:80)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
     at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:459)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1385)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1338)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
     at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:107)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
     at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST_View_notifyMouse_4f1a8388c3763e6ef91b5795c9a3bb669af40a28(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
     at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:597)
     at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll) not found in resource path ()
     at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1033)
     at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:989)
     at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:195)
     at com.sun.jna.Structure.setAlignType(Structure.java:291)
     at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:208)
     at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:204)
     at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:191)
     at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:183)
     at pcap.jdk7.internal.NativeMappings$ErrorBuffer.<init>(NativeMappings.java:734)
     at pcap.jdk7.internal.NativeMappings$ErrorBuffer.<init>(NativeMappings.java:731)
     at pcap.jdk7.internal.DefaultService.<init>(DefaultService.java:33)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)                                                                                           
     at java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780)
     ... 51 more
```

**Code that fails:**

```
var service = Service.Creator.create("PcapService"); **//This line throws the exception**
for (Interface device : service.interfaces()) {
  ...
}
```

**Dependencies added:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>     
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ardikars.pcap</groupId>
        <artifactId>pcap</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ardikars.pcap</groupId>
       <artifactId>pcap-jdk7</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Basically the problem is that dll file is not added to the native image. You need to add *.dll to the resourcesList or run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` first, and then build again. However, it is possible that the dll is not extracted from the jar. Some libraries have a way so set an alternative path with a system.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after comment of @JosePereda.

By running `mvn gluonfx:runagent` the necessary configuration was automatically added to **resources/META-INF.nativeimages/** files.
After that compiled again with `mvn gluonfx:build` and the app run successfully and I was able to query the function.

@JosePereda Thanks one more time crack!